# Lambda to return the object containing min value of a field that output from a fuction

Tags: c#, lambda

```
private Ent FindNearestEntity()
{
    Ent result = null;
    double closestEntDistance = double.MaxValue;

    foreach (var ent in ents)
    {
        if (ent.isEnabled)
        {
            var currentLocation = ent.x;

            var currentDistance = VectorLength(currentLocation);

            if (result == null || currentDistance < closestEntDistance)
            {
                result = ent;
                closestEntDistance = currentDistance;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

How do I achieve the above functionality in a single statement? Here is one of my not so successful attempt.

```
return ents.Where(e => e.isEnabled).Min<Ent>(e => VectorLength(e.x));
```

Comment: What's wrong with your LINQ query? What isn't working?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the Min expression is trying to convert the VectorLength, which is a double to an Ent. Which throws an Error.

Comment: Remove the generic type parameter `Ent`. Just use `Min(e => VectorLength(e.x));`

Comment: that will return the field, I want it to be the object that has the field.

Comment: One possibility would be `ents.Where(e => e.isEnabled).OrderBy(e => VectorLength(e.x)).First();`

Comment: The code you wrote seems to work for me, can you post the exception?

Comment: According to the duplicate marked by @ChrisF I came out with this answer:

`return ents.Aggregate((curMin, e) => (curMin == null || (e.isEnabled && VectorLength(e.x) < VectorLength(curMin.x)) ? e : curMin));`

Comment: but the answer I came out seems to be sub-optimal because it is running the VectorLength function everytime, when I could cache it. So I think @YuvalItzchakov answer fits better in this situation.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov is not very good as it runs in O(n*log(n)), but the code you wrote should work, maybe try `return ents.Where(e => e.isEnabled).Min<Ent, double>(e => VectorLength(e.x));`

Comment: @psuedoDust that won't compile.

Comment: Can you post the error your code throws?